# passing parameter (with ref) and string array into a .net function with clr pythonnet

Tags: python, .net, string, clr, python.net

I have this function  in a dll that i imported via clr in python with asNetArray function that i found somewhere in the net.

```
public static double DrawdownTable(ref System.Array resDrawdown, ref System.Array resPeak, ref System.Array resThrough, ref System.Array resRecover, System.Array dateVector, System.Array security)
```

```
resDrawdown = asNetArray(np.array([]))
    resPeak = asNetArray(np.array([]))
    resThrough = asNetArray(np.array([]))
    resRecover = asNetArray(np.array([]))

    date=date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').to_list()
    date = Array[str](date)
    #table =  Engine.DrawdownTable(asNetArray(date),asNetArray(security))
    (result,resDrawdown,resPeak,resThrough,resRecover) = Engine.DrawdownTable(resDrawdown,resPeak,resThrough,resRecover,date,security)
```

Unfortunately i have this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: L'index se trouve en dehors des limites du tableau.
   à System.Array.InternalGetReference(Void* elemRef, Int32 rank, Int32* pIndices)
   à System.Array.SetValue(Object value, Int32 index)
   à DrawdownTable(Array& resDrawdown, Array& resPeak, Array& resThrough, Array& resRecover, Array dateVector, Array security)
```

I can't understand why and also it's a bit complicated to search things on pythonnet as there is not much documentation for beginners.
I tried to defined my ref argument with `Array[str]([])` but without success.

Answer (score 0):

The error you see happens in your `DrawdownTable`. It got the arrays you created, but you tried to access an element (likely from one of them) with bad index.